# convert all png in a folder to dds

Tags: python

Does anyone know how I can save the output file with the same name as the input file in python? If I hardcode then output file as abc.dds it works. When I try to to use *.dds it does not work..

The reason is because I need the code to go through the current folder  and save the png file as the same name but with the .dds extension...

any idea? thanks!

Code below:

```
from wand.image import Image
from glob import glob

 #Get list of all images filenames to include
image_names = glob('*.png')

 #Create new Image, and extend sequence
with Image() as img:
    img.sequence.extend( [ Image(filename=f) for f in image_names ] )

    img.save(filename='abc.dds')
```

any  idea? thanks.

Comment: Which of the globbed names do you want to use? You're extending an image using all the images you found so you have a single image at the end.

Comment: I ideally want each file to be treated individually, I can have 20.png files all with different names and I am trying to get 20 .dds files all with the keeping the name from the .png that they were converted from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ordering of your original logic is a little off. From what you say you want in the comments, you want to just traverse all the PNG files in some directory and then convert them to DDS files with the same file name.

In your original, you're creating an image sequence, which is used more for animations like GIFs. Instead, what you want to do instead is iterate through all the PNGs in your directory, load them as `Image` objects, and then re-save them as `dds` files using `dxt5` compression, which is the DDS file-type compression.

In my code below, I use `pathlib.Path.glob` which works pretty much the same way as `glob.glob`, and then I just use `.stem` on the individual glob files to get the name of the file, without the extension, and then reusing them to make the `.dds` file names.

```
from pathlib import Path

from wand.image import Image

if __name__ == "__main__":
    png_files = Path(".").glob("*.png")

    for png_file in png_files:
        with Image(filename=png_file) as img:
            img.compression = "dxt5"
            base_file = png_file.stem
            dds_file = f"{base_file}.dds"
            img.save(filename=dds_file)
```